# Extjs line chart not drawing series when the first record is null

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts, linechart

Extjs line chart not drawing series when the first record is null.

Year    data1    data2

---

2010    (null)   99
 2011    100.00   100
 2012    0        30
 2013    (null)   0

In this my first series is data1 and second series is data2.

data2 is being rendered where as data1 line series is not there at all. b'coz the first record is null.

what needs to be done in this case?

Comment: This sounds identical to a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28278057) I asked several months ago. I posted the same thing in detail to Sencha Support and it was acknowledged as a feature-request (which is still "pending" indefinitely). As already suggested, the easiest option is just to zero the null entries - I wouldn't advise digging any deeper as the package is quite restrictive and fundamentally lacking (it gave me a headache anyway...). Personally I'd look at integrating a third-party charting library such as [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com) or [NVD3](http://nvd3.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried replacing null with a zero(O)?